# evaluating $\int{sin(\frac{3x}{3x+2y})}dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have a region bounded by the lines $y=x$, $y=2x$, and $y=1-x$

I need to evaluate

$$\iint_R\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2x+y}\right) dxdy$$

I already figured the bounds of the region require splitting the integral into two parts, however I'm having trouble with the actual integration:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}{\int_y^\frac{y}{2}{\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2x+y}\right) dx}dy} + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{2}{3}\int_\frac{y}{2}^{1-y} \sin\left(\frac{3x}{2x+y}\right)dxdy $$

Comment: Is the denominator of the fraction $2x+y$ or $2x+2y$? There's an inconsistency in your equations.

Comment: @JoshB. Thanks, I edited the post to correct the denominator, it's $2x+y$

Comment: If you convert this integral to polar you get $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\arctan(2)} \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}}r\sin\Big(\frac{3}{2+\tan(\theta)}\Big)drd\theta$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\arctan(2)}\frac{1}{\sin(2\theta)+1}\sin\Big(\frac{3}{2+\tan(\theta)}\Big)d\theta$$ Wolfram doesn't provide an exact value for this integral, which makes me suspicious, but I'm not ready to conclude this cannot be evaluated with some multivariate transformation.

Comment: @MatthewPilling But Wolfram provides value for both integrals in the question.

Comment: @MathLover: What does Wolfram say for the value of this integral?

Comment: The most "natural" transformation (in my opinion) that morphs $R$ into a square is the one defined by $$(u,v)=\Bigg(\frac{y}{x},x+y\Bigg)$$ But this is giving me the double integral $$\int_0^1\int_1^2\frac{v}{(u+1)^2}\sin\bigg(\frac{3}{u+2}\bigg)dudv$$ which boils down $$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}\sin\bigg(\frac{3}{u+2}\bigg)du$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling it gives values of $0.0485147$ and $0.015542$

Comment: @MathLover I thought you were saying it provided you with an *exact* value like $\pi/e^2$ or something, not a decimal approximation. Anyway, I would bet money that the integral in the original problem was $\sin\bigg(\frac{3x}{x+y}\bigg)$ instead of $\sin\bigg(\frac{3x}{2x+y}\bigg)$ If we had $\sin\bigg(\frac{3x}{x+y}\bigg)$ as our integrand, then the substitution $$u=y/x,v=x+y$$ would transform $\int \int _R \sin \bigg(\frac{3x}{x+y}\bigg)dA$ into $$\int_0^1 \int_1^2 \frac{v}{(u+1)^2}\sin\bigg(\frac{3}{u+1}\bigg)dudv=\frac{\cos(1)-\cos(3/2)}{6}$$